# How can I acquire text from text filed

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-studio

I am new to programming and am trying to design a Fortune Teller game according to a book "Applescript studio programming for the absolute beginner".

When the player types the question in the Text Field and then clicks the "Ask" button, the program will randomly give the answer "Yes" "No" "Maybe".

I did as the book instructed. But when I press build and go in Xcode, it returns "2018-04-08 22:22:01.189 Fortune Teller[14813:245050] *** -[AppDelegate clicked:]: Can’t get every text of TextField of class "NSObject". (error -1728)"

Can anyone tell me how to fix that problem? Thank you!

The following is the interface. 
[image]

The following is the code.

-- This code runs whenever the player clicks on the Ask button
 on clicked_(theObject)

-- Assign the text entered by the player clicks on the Ask button
set the question to contents of text field "textbox" of window "main"

-- Display an error message if the player did not enter any text
if question = "" then
    display dialogue ¬
        "Sorry, but you did not ask a question. Please try again."¬
        buttons {"OK"} 
        return
end if
-- Assign a random number between 1 and 3 to a variable named random
set randomNo to a random number from 1 to 3

if randomNo = 1 then
    set answer to "Yes"
end if

if randomNo = 2 then
    set answer to "No"
end if

if randomNo = 3 then
    set answer to "Maybe"
end if

beep -- Play a beep sound to get player's intention

display display dialog "Question:" & question & "Answer:" & answer & buttons {"OK"} 
end clicked_

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. Get a new book.

Mac OS X 10.6 replaced AppleScript Studio with AppleScript-ObjC. Unlike ASS, which gave you AppleScript-style commands and classes for controlling Cocoa, ASOC is just a thin wrapper around Cocoa’s Objective-C APIs, meaning you need to learn *those* APIs before you can use it.

Shane Stanley used to have an e-book on GUI programming with ASOC, but I think it’s out of print unfortunately. There was an introductory chapter to GUI programming with ASOC at the end of Apress’s Learn AppleScript, 3rd edition (which I co-wrote), and the AppleScript Users mailing list/MacScripter.net forum can no doubt point you to whatever other resources are out there. But all in all, documentation and support is not great. You pretty much have to learn ObjC in order to use ASOC effectively, even if just to read the Cocoa documentation and translate it to AS syntax in your head. And it hasn’t been updated in several years so lacks support for newer ObjC features such as blocks, which means you end up writing ObjC code anyway if you want to use those APIs.

..

Frankly, if your goal is to write your own GUI Apps (rather than automate existing ones), I strongly recommend you bite the bullet and learn Apple’s Swift. While it’s a bloated mess of a language, it’s well-documented, widely-used, and 100% supported by Apple [unlike AppleScript]. With Apple recently announcing a new GUI framework for writing iOS and macOS apps, it’s clear that Swift is the future.

If you need a bit of AppleScript to talk to other apps, it is possible to mix Swift and AS in the same app; but that’s a different question for a separate post.

Comment: Wow, it is astonishing and exciting to get the answer from the co-writer of Learn AppleScript. I know the book but haven’t placed an order to get it yet.
As you said, it is true that documentation and support for Applescript is not great and clearly I should try Swift.

Anyway, your replay really helps a lot and thank you for your suggestion! 
Have a good day.

Comment: I also found the e-book “Everyday AppleScriptObjC " written by Shane Stanley and paid to buy it. After some reading I realized that I might go the wrong direction. AppleScriptObjC involves many concepts of Objective-C, and is somewhat different from Applescript.  I also figured out that  NS of NSString refers to NeXT Step. It just made me confused why the code shows the word NSString in the script every time I opened a new Applescript-Cocoa project in Xcode.